# How to overcome mental blocks when studying?

Tags: attention, concentration

Let's suppose hypothetically I am subject A for extended periods of time and devoting my all my time to it. At some point, I feel I hit a plateu , similar to trying to drive in mud, I feel stuck without being able to progress further.

What would be the best move to overcome this stuck feeling? I see three possible options of proceeding:

1. I drop the subject I am doing and try something else for a few days time
2. Continue trying to bash through exercises on the subject
3. I drop the subject for a few hours and return

I have repeatedly tried (2) and (3) with not much success. I am starting to think (1) maybe the best way , has there been any research on how to over come learning difficulties when the student comes at a mental block in self studying?

Comment: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1/7604

Comment: There are similar questions already on the forum, such as [Are there researched approaches to learning a subject more quickly?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/20551/7001) and [Is it better to study multiple subjects simultaneously or focus on one subject intensely at a time?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/11034/7001)